# Relation between $a$ and $a^{-1}$ in integer rings about evenness

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-rings

Could I ask something seemingly simple?

Well, let $N$ be a positive odd number (the reason why I set $N$ to be odd is I could actually  solve the problem when $N$ is even which is easy) and $a$ is an integer such that $\gcd{(a, N)}=1$ (that is, $a$ has the multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_N$.)

I think when $a$ is odd, then $a^{-1} \text{mod} N$ is also odd, and reversely when $a$ is even, then $a^{-1} \text{mod} N$ is also even.

Am I right? As I said, when $N$ is even, it can be easily proved. But when $N$ is odd, it becomes a little confusing.

I expect the answer to be 'Yes' and the proof to not be complicated.

Could any body help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, $N = 5, a = 2$. $a^{-1} = 3$. Besides, parity isn't well-defined or useful in $\mathbb{Z}/(N)$ for odd $N$, since $2$ is invertible there.

Comment: @DanielFischer: It would be useful to turn the comment into an answer, so the problem can be put to bed.

Answer (score 4):

When you're working in $\mathbb{Z}_N$ with an odd $N$, there is no well-defined distinction between "even" and "odd" because $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_N$, so it divides all elements.

If you take it to mean the parity of the element of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the range $0 \leqslant k < N$ representing the element, then the inverse of an "odd" element can be "even", for example in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, we have $3^{-1} = 2$, and in $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$, we have $11^{-1} = 2$.